# Install Win 98, XP, 7, 8 and Linux without loosing current configuration

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot

I would like to install Windows 98, XP and 8 Dev Preview alongside of Linux and Win 7 and would like to do so without loosing my current config.

Here is my current setup:

- Drive 0: [150Gb Linux / 150Gb Linux]
- Drive 1: [150Gb Windows 7 / 150GB Empty ]

I'd like to use the empty partition on Drive 1 to install Windows 98, XP and Windows 8 Dev preview and not lose my current setup.

I don't mind using VHD or even purchasing a good Boot Loader. I did look into [Acronis Disk Director](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/) but am unsure if there are better, more suitable alternatives. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Please, I do not want Virtual Machines as they don't allow me to make full use of my video card nor the processor.

Comment: Any reason you can just create VMs for each OS?  They wouldn't need to all be running simultaneously.

Comment: Good lord, Windows 98? You do know that it's a 14 year old OS, don't you? :)

Comment: Why so many OS's?

Comment: Hi, yes I do know win 98 is old, thanks. The two Linux distros are just for playing around. I know a VM works just fine, but I like immerse myself in the linux experience every couple of months. Then when I'm done messing about after a week or so, I'm usually back to Windows. Windows 98 for some old school games I have been wanting to play and still not sure about Windows XP. I would like Win 8 dev preview installed to test out the development portion. Win 7 is primary. The bottom line, the ones I would like ABSOLUTELY are Win 98, 7 and Linux.

Comment: It may be because this is kind of ridiculous, and a bit impractical. You're going to have one really messed up setup going.

Comment: Well I have it this way now without win98. And it works very well for me. I'm sorry that I don't fit your guys status quo but I like setting up my system this way. Just so you are aware you are downvoting my preference for running my own system and not my question as it is a perfectly valid question. Truthfully now one has answered the question yet.

Comment: I think you need to consider that this is a very narrow situation that isn't likely to work particularly well. What have you tried so far that hasn't worked? Have you made any attempts at adding Windows 98? If you've got it all working fine with everything but Windows 98 right now, perhaps you could run just Windows 98 in a VM? I guarantee you that a VM on modern hardware will still be orders of magnitude faster than the original hardware Win98 was designed for would have been.

Comment: The problem is the lack of a question. Install Win 8 and 98 on the empty partition, and let Grub (of your Linux distro) detect the OSs.

Comment: @nhinkle... the last time i tried to run a game in the VM I couldn't get it to work right. However, your point has gotten me to try again. Now that I think about it, the last time I tried with VirtualPC. Perhaps VirtualBox will be a better candidate.

Comment: as for this not being a question, perhaps instead of writing: _"and would like to do so without loosing my current config."_ I should have written: _"is there a way I can do this without loosing my current configuration?"_.

Comment: @Psirus, the object is to not loose the current configuration. I wasn't sure if I install Windows 98 over 7, if GRUB would then pick it up. I didn't want to find out either as my current system runs nice and stable. I was hoping someone may have experience with this.

Answer (score 2):

1. Select your "host" OS. Sounds like this will either be Linux or Windows 7.
2. Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).
3. Create VMs for each OS, and install the OSes.
4. (Optional) After installation, take snapshots of each VM and archive for future use.
5. Profit?